# Cannot enter credentials for aws code commit to track local repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

When attempting to connect my AWS repository via HTTPS to my local repository (OSX), I cannot enter my credentials. When entering the command to clone the repo, it then prompts me for my username, which allows me to input. It then prompts me for my password but does not let me enter any information, instead a lock symbol appears. When I press return without entering anything, I receive an error.Is it something with AWS permissions, or something I am doing wrong in the terminal?

I expect to simply input my username and password like the AWS tutorial.

I have already set up the AWS configure prompt.

```
"fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-
1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/DNA-AIR-CONDITIONING-HEATING/': The requested URL 
returned error: 403".
```

Comment: When it displays lick symbol you need to enter the password. It won't display any thing in the UI when you enter the password. You just need to type the password and press enter key. That's how it works on Linux and osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws configure` will not configure git access to your repo.

You need to setup your HTTPS Users by following [the guide in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html). These are special credentials and are not the same as your general AWS credentials.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Your explanation along with the documentation was helpful, I found the solution.

Comment: @KendallHayes Perfect. If you feel like i answered your question, i would appreciate if you mark it as an answer.